# how to logging func_name and filename

Tags: python, logging

I packaged a class Logger.

```
class Logger:
    def __init__(self, logfile):
        self.log_file = logfile

    def debug(self, message):
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                            format='%(asctime)-15s %(levelname)s %(module)s %(funcName)s %(lineno)d %(message)s',
                            datefmt='%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S',
                            filename=self.log_file,
                            filemode='w')
        logging.debug(message)
```

Then i create logger instance in main function.
Then i used this logger in another class file file1.

```
  def is_path_valid(self, dc_path):
      self.logger.debug('Entering with parameter dc_path: %s' %(dc_path))
```

But this log written in log file is "Tue, 19 Mar 2019 05:41:15 DEBUG ***logger debug*** 14 Entering with parameter dc_path: /disks". 
What i expected is "Tue, 19 Mar 2019 05:41:15 DEBUG ***file1 is_path_valid*** #line_number Entering with parameter dc_path: /disks"

How should i do?

Comment: Why create your own logger class, which, in this example at least, does not provide anything extra above the normal logging module. With the latter, you set the logger for a package or module (not the default root logger, i.e., not with `logging.basicConfig`), and inside the module, you use `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`.

Comment: Your custom logger only exposes one of the log levels, and reconfigures logging every time something is `debug`ged. I'd recommend looking at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) and sticking to more conventional patterns like that mentioned above.

Comment: Aside: don't use the `%` to concatenate your logging string with the variable(s) to be logged. Use `logger.debug('Entering with parameter dc_path: %s', (dc_path))` (comma instead of the second `%` sign). This saves some time behind the scenes, since the formatting is *only* done when the logging level is used.

Comment: I just pasted part code in this logger class(such as error level print logging.exception). I need to log data in several modules, so i think it is better to create own logger class.

Answer (score 0):

You could eventually use the [traceback](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) module:

```
import traceback

def your_method(param):
    print(traceback.format_stack())  # the stacktrace formatted
    print(traceback.extract_stack())  # the stacktrace as a list, you could only get the last item

your_method(1)
```

You could achieve that by transforming your debug() method by something like that:

```
def debug(self, message):
    logging.debug('%s - %s', traceback.extract_stack()[-1], message)
```

> NB: you don't need to call the `basicConfig` method each time you call the debug() method, just call it when your logger in instanciated; See more about good practices with logging there: https://realpython.com/python-logging/

Comment: Thanks. But if it is too heavy to get track stack? i want to find an easy way.

Comment: Why would it be "too heavy to get the stacktrace"?

Comment: I think traceback.extract_stack()[-1] should be slow, and i don't need to get stack trace, just want to use logging to log info.

Answer (score 0):

According to [logging Python official module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) in the section [LogRecord attributes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) and in order to get the expected log output:

> Tue, 19 Mar 2019 05:41:15 DEBUG file1 is_path_valid #line_number
>   Entering with parameter dc_path: /disks

Your format log record attributes should looks like this:

```
'%(asctime)-15s %(levelname)s %(module)s %(filename)s %(lineno)d %(message)s'
```

Notice the change from `funcName` to `filename` because what you are looking for is the file name and also you'll obtain: Filename portion of pathname.

Comment: No, it is not the root cause, and i also tried filename but it is still logger.py not calling module filename in log file.

Answer (score 0):

Have fixed this problem and don't need to write own logger class.